Proving that complex function has real laurent coefficients
I read a book about time series analysis, and at some point one bumps into complex analysis. There is a statistical question, to which the answer lies in the following Laurent series decomposition problem:
Let $\varphi(z), \theta(z)$ be two polynomials with real coefficients.
Also $\varphi(z)$ has no zeros on the unit circle. Therefore the two functions:
$$\frac{1}{\varphi(z)}, \ \frac{\theta(z)}{\varphi(z)}$$
can be written as a Laurent series at $0$ on some annulus which includes the unit circle:
$$\frac{1}{\varphi(z)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$$
$$\frac{\theta(z)}{\varphi(z)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n$$
I want to prove that $a_n, b_n$ are real numbers.
Is there an elegant way to prove this? Is it true?

This is obvious since for example $1/\overline{\phi(\bar z)}$ is equal to $1/\phi(z)$ on the real segment of the annulus hence everywhere in the annulus by analytic continuation and its Laurent coefficients are $\bar a_n$; same for the other

Note that (by conjugation) $$1/\overline{\phi(\bar z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \bar a_nz^n$$ but the fact that $\phi$ has real coefficients means that on the real segment of the annulus hence everywhere in the annulus by analytic continuation we have $$1/\overline{\phi(\bar z)}=1/\phi(z)$$ so indeed $\bar a_n=a_n$ and $a_n$ is real. The same argument works for $\theta/\phi$ and $b_n$

So the same argument would work for any holomorphic function on some domain which is real for real values?

As long as the domain is symmetric wr to the $x$ axis so $\bar z$ is in the domain iff $z$ is in the domain - or more generally if $D \cap \bar D$ is conjected
